# Windows 7 and autoexec.bat

Tags: windows, autoexec

I am not sure whether `autoexec.bat` is supported under Windows 7. I need to run some commands at startup but before any user logon.

Comment: Should probably ask this in the [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/), not here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to run a script directly, but you can easily make it run as a service using for example srvany.exe (short for "serve any"). Details can be found here: [Best srvany.exe for Windows XP and Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/146141/best-srvany-exe-for-windows-xp-and-windows-7)

Alternatively, using the Windows Task Scheduler should be able to do the trick as well:
http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/67503-task-create-run-program-startup-log.html

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't no more.

Yopu can put your startup applications in the Startup folder of the Start button (right click on the Startup folder / Open).